# Replacing all selected elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

I'm trying to select all spans with class .normal on my site, cut the first character and add € as the last character. I'm trying really hard but it just doesn't work even when I try to just replace that with "abc" or any string.

My javascript looks like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var prices = document.querySelectorAll('span.normal');

for (i=0; i<prices.length; i++) {
  prices[i].textContent = prices[i].substring(1) + "€"; 
}

}

});
```

Comment: `prices[i].textContent = prices[i].textContent.substring(1) + "€";`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks, but like I said, event if I do 
    prices[i].textContent = "abc"; 
it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? And use `innerHTML` if target browser is `<IE9`..Have you included `jQuery` ? Why it is not tagged ? Check console for errors..

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your code

Comment: @Adersh yea, I pasted wrongly. doesn't work anyway

Comment: @RayonDabre that's a pretty big website coded with internal syntax so I don't know what should I put in my JS Fiddle, I'll try

Comment: Does your scenario passed through the tests provided in earlier comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery already how about making it completely in jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span.normal').each(function() {
   $(this).text($(this).text().substring(1) + '€');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>abc</span>
<span class="normal">abc</span>
<span>abc</span>
<span class="normal">abc</span>
```

Comment: Solved it perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var prices = document.querySelectorAll('span.normal');

for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
  prices[i].innerHTML = prices[i].innerHTML.substring(1) + "€"; 
}
```

```css
.normal{
  font-color:black;
}
```

```html
<span class=normal >3543</span>
<span class=normal >34534</span>
```